# How to add multiple passwords to this PHP code?

Tags: php, html

I don't know PHP and have downloaded this code that works perfectly fine.

I add this code on top of any *.php file and it makes that page, password protected that only opens up if you type the password which in this case is 1234.

Now, I want to add 3 passwords instead of 1. I just don't know where to edit this code.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit_pass']) && $_POST['pass'])
{
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 if($pass=="1234")
 {
  $_SESSION['password']=$pass;
 }
 else
 {
  $error="Incorrect Pssword";
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['page_logout']))
{
 unset($_SESSION['password']);
}
?>
```

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['password']=="1234")
{

?>
```

```
<form method="post" action="" id="logout_form">
    <input type="submit" name="page_logout" value="Logout">
</form>

    
   <?php
}
else
{
 ?>     

         <form method="post" action="">
             <div>Protected Content</div>
             <br />
             <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Type your password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_pass" value="Login">
            <br /><br />
            <div><?php echo $error;?></div>
        </form>

   <?php
}
?>
```

Where should I, add what, to be able to have 3 possible passwords?

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you ask. You need to be much more specific. What _excatly_ does "it adds a password to my page" mean? And what _exactly_ do you mean with "I want to add 3 passwords instead of 1."?

Comment: `if($pass=="1234" || $pass=="5678"`...etc. but really...use a database.

Comment: I add this code on top of any *.php file and it makes that php page, password protected that only opens up if you type the password which in this case is 1234.

Now, I want to add 3 more passwords instead of 1. I just don't know where to edit this code.

Comment: Well I literally just showed you

Comment: Thanks a ton @ADyson it worked liked a charm. I didn't get your point about using a database though.

Comment: The point was it would be better to store the passwords hashed in a database then it's more secure but also easier to change them. Hard coding them into the application is inflexible and not particularly secure

Comment: @ADyson now I got your point. most definitely it's a more secured approach to save the password on the server side rather than client side, and also much easier to change the password once, rather than multiple changes on different files.

problem is I don't have PHP knowledge and finding a simple to use code that can make a *.php file password protected, is super difficult.

otherwise, I'm sure experts like you can easily change the same code I have shared here, to call a password, stored inside a database, rather than putting it there inside the body of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you may edit password checking line like this:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit_pass']) && $_POST['pass'])
{
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 $available_passwords = ['12345','pass123','myOtherPassword'];

 if(in_array($pass,$ava_passwords))
 {
  $_SESSION['password']=$pass;
 }
 else
 {
  $error="Incorrect Pssword";
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['page_logout']))
{
 unset($_SESSION['password']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code, I just don't know how and where to put your code in the body of the code I shared. I think what @ADyson suggested, for me who doesn't know anything about php, is a faster fix.

Comment: I will change my code for you :)